# Can anyone check if I chained my constructor correctly please

Tags: java

Class I intend to call:

```
public LibraryCard(int MaxBorrowedBooks, int CardID)
{
     bookLimit = MaxBorrowedBooks;
     cardReference = "CardID" + CardID;
     currentBooks = 0; 
}
```

The actual call:

```
public LibraryCard issueCard()
{
    LibraryCard thisCardID = new LibraryCard (limitOnBorrowing, numberOfBorrowers);
    numberOfBorrowers ++;
    return thisCardID;
}
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is call the constructor from the LibraryCard class and have the number of Borrowers increase in increments of 1.

I am new to programming and Java as well, hence the incorrect terminology.

Comment: there is no question in your post

Comment: The call is fine in terms of the form, etc., but it seems very odd to be passing `numberOfBorrowers` for a parameter called `CardID`. I'd expect you to be passing some kind of ID, not a count. (Side note: Those parameter names should start with a lower-case character: `maxBorrowedBooks`, `cardID` or `cardId`.) The `issueCard` method could also use postfix increment and be a one-liner: `return new LibraryCard(limitOnBorrowing, numberOfBorrowers++);`

Comment: Why don't you just try it? It seems to be doing what you want it to do.